# Lambda compareTo() not being recognized

Tags: java, api, lambda

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<StockDTO> findById(@PathVariable Long id){
    List<StockDTO> list = new ArrayList<>();
    StockDTO dto1= new StockDTO();
    dto1.setId(1L);
    dto1.setNameStock("AF");
    dto1.setPrice(100D);
    dto1.setVariation(10D);
    dto1.setDateStock(LocalDate.now());
    StockDTO dto2 = new StockDTO();
    dto2.setId(2L);
    dto2.setNameStock("AF2");
    dto2.setPrice(200D);
    dto2.setVariation(20D);
    dto2.setDateStock(LocalDate.now());
    list.add(dto1);
    list.add(dto2);

    StockDTO dtoSelect = list.stream().filter(x -> x.getId().compareTo(id)== 0).findFirst().get();
            return ResponseEntity.ok(dtoSelect);
}
```

I'm creating an endpoint to list just a single object with findById, and using lambda to go through the list and find the id, but the terminal is acusing an error because of the compareTo(id) part.

*'java: long cannot be dereferenced'*

Need some help.

Comment: what do you expect `.compareTo(id)== 0` would do that ` == id` doesn't ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well `id` is `long`, so you should use `==` instead of `.compareTo()`

```
StockDTO dtoSelect = list.stream().filter(x -> x.getId() == id).findFirst().get();
```

Or "box" the `id` using `Long.valueOf(id)`

...btw, maybe you should use `.equals()` instead of `.compareTo() == 0`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. It's funny because in the video of the guy taughting, it worked like that, he said the compareTo part is used compare (of course) the long and it returns -1, 0 or 1 if it's lower, equals, higher respectively.

Comment: @HugoPorfirio yes of course, but in your case you only need equality, so you can use `.equal()`

Comment: Thanks, it's working with the equality, the x.get() does not accept any methods.

Comment: There's also [`Long.compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#compare(long,%20long)) to compare primitive longs.

Comment: @HugoPofirio `compareTo` returns `< 0`, `0` or `> 0`. Don't rely on it being `-1`, `0` and `1`.

Answer (score 0):

The lambda is irrelevant. The message is telling you `x.getId()` returns a `long`, a [primitive type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) you can't call methods on. Just write `x.getId() == id`.